# How can I add strings to a dynamic array in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm a Uni student who just started learning c++. I was practicing and ran into an issue.
I have to add some strings (to be specific human names) to a dynamic array but I have some problems apparently.

My task specified code so far (I'm using sturct):

...

```
int FPQ=0;
string FP[MaxN+1];

for(int i=1; i<=N; ++i)
    {
        int Perc=(People[i].Point)*100/P;
        if( Perc >= 90)
       {
            FP[FPQ]=Person[i].Name;
            FPQ=FPQ+FPQ;
        }
    }
```

When I check the results FPQ has the right value yet FP has no names in it (or at least the standard console output doesn't show). What did I do wrong?

Comment: Whenever you think "dynamic array" your next thought should always be [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Then it would be extremely easy to add new elements.

Comment: By the way, if `FPQ` is equal to zero, what would the result of `FPQ+FPQ` be?

Comment: Array indices begin with 0, not 1. The line `FPQ=FPQ+FPQ;` doesn't increment the variable, it doubles it.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> FP;` -- This is what you are looking for.

Comment: In C++, a "dynamic array" is called `std::vector`.  So a dynamic array of strings looks like `std::vector<std::string> v; v.push_back("first"); v.push_back("second");`

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: yeah, I messed the code up. It's supposed to be 1+FPQ. Thanks for mentioning. The actual code doesn't have that problem.

Comment: And btw can't I solve my issue without using vectors?

Comment: ***can't I solve my issue without using vectors?*** That would be a poor solution but its doable. Modern `c++` teaches you that you almost never have to use manual memory management.

Comment: since we haven't learnt about vectors I think I'd prefer not using them.

Comment: Then lookup `new[]` and `delete[]` or use fixed sized arrays where the size of the array is fixed at compile time.

Comment: "I have to add some strings (to be specific human names) to a dynamic array" --
IMHO, a dynamic array is allocated using new (and released using delete).  Thus, FP is something else.   FYI - most std::string implementations keep their elements in dynamic memory anyway.   But even then, std::vector<std::string> would be my preferred approach.  Yes, with extra care and more work and testing, you should be able to get dynamic arrays to do what you need.  Consider taking the time to replicate the assignment using std::vectors.  You might appreciate why I prefer it.

Comment: "since we haven't learnt about vectors I think I'd prefer not using them." using vectors is as beginner friendly as c++ can get, while using dynamic c-style arrays is difficult to get right and easy to get extremely wrong. If you are not allowed to use vectors, thats a different story of course...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone for helping me. As it turns out, I'm dumb and didn't manage to write a proper for loop for displaying the FP's values. But thank you so much for helping. We're not allowed to use vectors (yet), but I'll check them out! :)